# SonarQube 6.3 OutOfMemoryError scanning large XML file(s)

Tags: xml, sonarqube, out-of-memory

I'm scanning a folder of XML files (total 472MB) containing several small to big  files. A couple of them are around 70/80MB.

using:

- sonarqube-6.3
- sonar-scanner-3.0.0.702-windows
- Microsoft Server 2012 RS2 14g ram, multi core Xeon
- XML plugin using 27 active rules.
- env var SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS = -Xmx10G

Combined java memory use during scanning of the complete folder will rise and rise, eventually leading to:

```
*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pidblabla.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [i.e. 314342113 bytes in 4.624 secs]*
```

Is there a way to fix this, or should I focus on decreasing the size of the xmls?

Comment: The value you set for SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS does not seem to be taken into account as the heap dump is only 314MB.

Comment: You should provide full debug logs (_sonar.verbose=true_) of the analysis.